# Hard foam pad replacement

Tags: maintenance, rubber

I think this is an Arts and Craft question.

I am looking to replace a hard foam pad on a sander. Manufacture wants over $20, but I know I can make one for a lot less.

The pad would need to be 4 x 4 x 1/8 inch thick and fairly hard.

I can trim a sheet down.

Appreciate any ideas. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I bought a piece of 1/16" rubber sheet. Glued it to bottom of old pad on sander.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ggm4j56fym0mdl/20180827_122005.jpg?dl=0

Because of the extra thickness, the sand paper is a little harder to fit between clamps.

Comment: +1 for providing your solution... you can accept it so the question appears answered.

Answer (score 0):

Spray some Dow Great Stuff on a glass pane, then press it down flat with another glass pane to the approximate thickness you need.  Prop the top glass pane up with pencils and give the foam time to harden.  Then separate the glass by turning the top pane (don't lift the corners or the glass might break) and scrape your new foam pad off the bottom pane with a spatula.
Finally, cut it to fit your sander.

For a different, less grainy consistency, try Plasti-Grip in place of the Great Stuff.  It is softer, but it is smoother.  You may need to build up a clay wall on the bottom pane to help the thinner liquid reach the desired thickness.